# Java 8 Convert List of List of String to Map

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-8

I have `List<List<String>>`. I want to convert it to Map based on a particular element of inner List.

I tried

```
ddList.stream().flatMap(x -> x.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), String::length)));
```

It is not working. What is going wrong here?

Comment: Show us some sample input and output data so that the transformation is clear.

Comment: You're calling `flatMap` with a `Map`, which is incorrect. You probably meant to close the parenthesis here: `.flatMap(x -> x.stream())`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be:

```
Map<String, Integer> sMap = 
    ddMap.stream()
         .flatMap(x -> x.stream())
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),
                                   String::length));
```

P.S. if the input `List`s contain any duplicate elements, this code will throw an exception. You can eliminate the duplicates with `distinct`:

```
Map<String, Integer> sMap = 
    ddMap.stream()
         .flatMap(x -> x.stream())
         .distinct()
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),
                                   String::length));
```

EDIT:

Based on your comment, you don't need `flatMap` at all, but something like this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> sMap = 
    ddMap.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(l -> l.get(0), // or some other member 
                                                  // of the inner List
                                   Function.identity()));
```

Comment: I received `java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.util.List`

Comment: In that case, ddMap contains elements which are not `List<String>`. Perhaps you used raw types and unsafe casts somewhere. @ruhewo

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am getting `List<List<String>>` from a JPA Hibernate query. I want to get the Map of inner list with a particular element as Key of the Map. So the output should be like `Map<String, List<String>>`

Comment: @ruhewo then why did you use `String::length` (which returns int) as the value mapper? See if the edit answer is what you want. That said, the exception you got implies that your List contains an Object[] element.